# Inheritance and generics java android

Tags: android, generics, inheritance, abstract-class, extend

New to inheritance and generics so bear with me if my question is stupid:

I have the following:

```
public abstract class car {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    public car (long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public final long getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public final String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}

public class sedan extends car {
    public sedan(long id, String name) {
        super (id, name);
    }
    ...
}

public class jeep extends car {
    public jeep(long id, String name) {
        super (id, name);
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to extend the ArrayAdapter for a spinner as follows:

```
public class DropdownAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<car> {
    private Context context;
    private List<car> values;

    public DropdownAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<car> values) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem comes when I try to use it:

```
adapter = new DropdownAdapter (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstSedan);
```

will give me the error: The constructor DropdownAdapter (ScreenItemList, int, List< sedan >) is undefined

```
adapter = new DropdownAdapter (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstJeep);
```

will give me the error: The constructor DropdownAdapter (ScreenItemList, int, List< jeep >) is undefined

What is the issue here?  Why can't I use lstSedan or lstJeep as parameters when they are derived from car?  How do I resolve this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined a method that expects a parameter of type `List<a>`

```
  public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<a> values)
```

That is, it expects a list of items of type `a`.
But then you pass a parameter of type `b` that inherited `a`, instead of a parameter of type `List<b>`
Try to use this way:

```
  List<b> lstB= new ArrayList<b>();
  adapter = new SpinnerAdapter (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstB);
```

As JoxTraex said, you should read [java name convention](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)

**Update**: 
Sorry, I made a mistake. Because java doesn't allow passing `List<ChildClass>` parameter to `List<ParentClass>`, so you shouldn't use inheritance in this case. Try using generic

```
public class DropdownAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
private Context context;
private List<T> values;

public DropdownAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> values) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}
...
}
```

And this function call should work:

```
 adapter = new SpinnerAdapter (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstB);
```

Comment: Hi R4j.  It still does not work, not sure what the issue is.  I get the same error, I actually had a typo and was using a list already

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because of the name you have it, specifically SpinnerAdapter **ALREADY** exists in the SDK. You need to either explicitly state which one you're using or change the class name.

### Advice

Also FYI, you shouldn't call a class a useless name like A.